# How to render to PDF a specific HTML element using VBScript

Tags: html, pdf, printing, vbscript, hta

I've got this challenge: I need to *render a HTML table* (just the table), which is part of a more complex HTML document, *as a PDF*.

I could accept even a different format, i.e. XPS, but not a directly "editable" format such as txt, csv, xls.

I need to use **VBScript** only (or at most some javascript considering IE 9 limitations), since this is for a legacy HTA application.

I cannot use any third party software to achieve this, except CutePDF which is already installed.

I tried using the CSS print media descriptors, but I can't get rid of the default explorer header and footer (and I cannot access the registry to modify them, even temporarily).

I could use the default explorer header and footer only if I could modify them on the fly programmatically... But I could not find any info about this.

EDIT: maybe is it possible to reduce the page print mergins to 0 and prevent the header/footer "imposition"? I'm goining to check this...

Comment: Is your question about creating a pdf of a table, or getting rid of the default header and footer? Why can't you access registry? HTA has no limits to do that.

Comment: @Teemu I need to create a PDF out of a HTML table AND I need to get rid of the default header (which is Internet Explorer 11). I cannot access the registry because the user running the app has no access to registry and even if it had the access he could not change anything becasue of internal regulations.

Comment: Ok, after I tried several ways I just came to the conclusion that there is no viable solution other than modifying user settings on the registry. This is really ugly...